# How to save multiple Hibernate entities with non saved transient one-to-many relations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on saving multiple JPA entities coming as a JSON from external system. The incoming data is a list of Authors and Books linked as One-To-Many (one author can have 0..n books). When I have a single author it works as expected, I see corresponding inserts executed by Hibernate:

```
2022-10-17 12:49:18.056 DEBUG 25640 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into book (author_id, title, id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

But once I need to save multiple authors the behavior changes. It seems after saving the first author it tries to refresh something and invokes select query which ends with EntityNotFoundException because there is nothing actually saved into the DB at that moment:

```
2022-10-17 12:48:33.980 DEBUG 436 --- [           main] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Done entity load
2022-10-17 12:48:33.980 DEBUG 436 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Generated identifier: 1, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.Assigned
2022-10-17 12:48:33.981 DEBUG 436 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select book0_.id as id1_1_0_, book0_.author_id as author_i3_1_0_, book0_.title as title2_1_0_, author1_.id as id1_0_1_, author1_.name as name2_0_1_ from book book0_ left outer join author author1_ on book0_.author_id=author1_.id where book0_.id=?
...
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find com.sandbox.demo.sql.puzzle.Book with id 1; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.sandbox.demo.sql.puzzle.Book with id 1
```

Here are the entities and the code I use to reproduce the issue:

```
public class Author {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
public class Book {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private Author author;
}
```

```
public class Main {
    @Transactional
    public void saveData() {
        saveAuthor(0);
        saveAuthor(1); // The code works if this line is commented out
    }

    private void saveAuthor(int id) {
        Author author = new Author();
        author.setId(id);
        author.setName("NAME #" + id);

        Book book = new Book();
        book.setId(id);
        book.setTitle("TITLE #" + id);
        book.setAuthor(author);

        author.getBooks().add(book);

        authorDAO.save(author);
        bookDAO.save(book);
    }
}
```

How to properly save multiple entities with one-to-many relations?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I need to save the entity first. Then the save() method will return me the saved entity and I need to use it when specify one-to-many property:

```
private void saveAuthor(int id) {
        Author author = new Author();
        author.setId(id);
        author.setName("NAME #" + id);

        Book book = new Book();
        book.setId(id);
        book.setTitle("TITLE #" + id);

        // The code below does the trick
        Author savedAuthor = authorDAO.save(author);
        Book savedBook = bookDAO.save(book);

        savedAuthor.getBooks().add(savedBook);
        savedBook.setAuthor(savedAuthor);
    }
```